# XmlException for the '/' character hex value 0x2F cannot be included in a name

Tags: c#, xmlexception

How can I solve the exception generated?

```
        public static string[] getKeywords(string filename)  
        {  
            var xmlFile = new XElement(filename);  
            string[] keywords = xmlFile.Elements("Keyword")
                                       .Attributes("name")
                                       .Select(n => n.Value).ToArray();  
            return keywords;  
        }
```

This generates this exception:

> System.Xml.XmlException was unhandled
>     Message=The '/' character, hexadecimal value 0x2F, cannot be included in a name.
>     Source=System.Xml

Comment: There's something wrong with your .xml file

Comment: Wow...first two answers from the top two users!

Comment: nobugz, I do not think there is something wrong with my xml file. I thought that at first and looked through it and there was nothing wrong.

Comment: Justin, yeah I know! And they are both right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new XElement(filename)` means create an element with the name from `filename` - do you mean `XElement.Load(filename)` ??

Answer (score 3):

You were trying to load the file name as XML hence it was throwing an exception.  This is what you wanted;

```
    public static string[] getKeywords(string filename)
    {
        var xmlFile = XElement.Load(filename);
        string[] keywords = xmlFile.Elements("Keyword").Attributes("name").Select(n => n.Value).ToArray();
        return keywords;
    }
```

Using the XElement.Load() method.